# adding "position: fixed;" prevents all scrolling, even on unattached elements

Tags: html, css

So, should be fairly straightfoward but i don't know why this isn't working (maybe i'm tired).

I'm trying to add position fixed to my webpage so i get a nice background that doesn't move, and then over the top, a text space where you can scroll (so the text moves, but the image stays the same). But when i add "position: fixed;" it just stops scrolling all together and as far as i'm aware, it should only stop the scrolling of the part it's attached to. 
So here's my html

```
<div id="Home-background">
        <div id="Home">
            <a name="Home"></a>
                <div class="page-padding"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

and my css

```
#Home-background {
    **position: fixed;**
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('Pictures/lords-fallen-art-wallpapers-1080p.jpg');
    background-size: 100%, 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    min-height: 700px;
}

#Home {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 400px;
    width:70%;
    min-height: 3000px;
    background:#ffffff;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

The marked position is what is causing the issue, but it should have no affect on the #Home set, right?

EDIT: I thought i should note, i am using other fixed elements ( i have a top bar and a menu bar at the side currently, both are fixed and both scroll till i add the fixed element as mentioned above. But having multiple fixed elements shouldn't stop other fixed elements from working either, right? (yes i've z-indexed them respectively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#Home-background` is wrapping the `#Home` div and will prevent scrolling if it is `position: fixed`

To place a fixed background, put a background on the body.

In your example it should look something like this:

- `no-repeat` prevents the background image from repeating
- `background-position: fixed` prevents the image from scrolling
- `background-size: 100% 100%` stretches the image to fit the body element

**Note:** The image in this example does not make it obvious that it is fixed, but it is :)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url('http://www.placehold.it/1000') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: fixed;
}
#Home {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 3000px;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Home">
  <a name="Home"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, the problem was "Home" being inside "Home-Background" although i still don't understand why that would break it.

The following solves my problem

```
<div id="Home-background"></div>
<div id="Home">
    <a name="Home"></a>
        <div class="page-padding"></div>
</div>
```